# CMake set Windows PATH environment variable only during install

Tags: windows, cmake, environment-variables

I have a **CMake** project that builds and installs everything correctly. The only issue is that I have to update the Windows PATH environment variable only for Windows platform and only during an install. I know how to detect Windows platform with

```
if (${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "Windows")
    xxx
endif()
```

I also know how to set an environment variable from Powershell with the **setx** command.  I do not know how to do this only when installing.

I have a toplevel CMakeLists

```
# minimum version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26.3)

#project
project(pasm VERSION 2.0)

#source code
add_subdirectory(source)

#unittests
add_subdirectory(unittests)
```

and in the source directory CMakeLists

```
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

#get_cmake_property(_variableNames VARIABLES)
#list (SORT _variableNames)
#foreach (_variableName ${_variableNames})
#    message(STATUS "${_variableName}=${${_variableName}}")
#endforeach()

# set _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS for Windows
if (${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "Windows")
    add_definitions(-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
endif()

# Bison
find_package(BISON REQUIRED)
BISON_TARGET(Bison_Parser pasm.y ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/pasm.tab.cc
    COMPILE_FLAGS "-rall"
    DEFINES_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/pasm.tab.h)

# For win_flex turn on --wincompat
find_package(FLEX REQUIRED)
string(FIND "${FLEX_EXECUTABLE}" "win_flex.exe" IS_WIN_FLEX)

if (NOT ${IS_WIN_FLEX} EQUAL -1)
    FLEX_TARGET(Flex_Scanner pasm.l ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/pasm.flex.cc
    COMPILE_FLAGS --wincompat)
else()
    FLEX_TARGET(Flex_Scanner pasm.l ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/pasm.flex.cc
    )
endif()

# set flex bison dependency   
ADD_FLEX_BISON_DEPENDENCY(Flex_Scanner Bison_Parser)

# parser scanner library
add_library(parser
    ${BISON_Bison_Parser_OUTPUTS}
    ${FLEX_Flex_Scanner_OUTPUTS}
    parseargs.cc 
)
    
# engine
add_library(engine 
    dictionary.cc
    error.cc 
    expand.cc 
    file.cc
    genlist.cc
    genoutput.cc
    globals.cc
    hash.cc
    memory.cc
    node.cc
    opcodes.cc       
    stacks.cc
    str.cc
    sym.cc
    pass.cc)
 
# executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    main.cc)

# force flex/bison first
add_dependencies(engine parser) 

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    parser 
    engine)

# include directory for main
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC 
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")

# include directory for parser
target_include_directories(parser PUBLIC
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")

# include directory for engine
target_include_directories(engine PUBLIC 
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")

# install
    install (TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

Comment: Why do you ever need PATH variable during the install stage? During that stage only `install` commands are executed. And the one you have - `install(TARGETS)` - doesn't use PATH at all.

Comment: I want the PATH set if the user installs the product,
The user does cmake --install PasmBuild.  
This installs the exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Pasm\bin  

To run  the .exe,  it needs to be part of the PATH

Comment: Oh, so you need PATH variable modification which remains active **after** installing. This is not what CMake does by itself. But **installers** may provide such capability. E.g. NSIS one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70791675/append-bin-folder-to-path-environement-variable-after-installation.

Comment: I added
if (${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "Windows")
    set(mypath $ENV{Path})    
    string(FIND "${mypath}" "\\Pasm\\" HAS_PATH)    

    if (NOT ${HAS_PATH} EQUAL -1)
        message(STATUS "Pasm path is set.")
    else()
        execute_process(COMMAND "PowerShell" "setx PATH %PATH%\";%PROGRAMFILES\(x86\)%\\Pasm\\bin;\"")
    endif()    
endif()

but I dont like it